# Ubuntu 23.10 (and 22.04/23.04) RTL USB wifi dongle has downloads slower than uploads

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, usb, realtek

I am really confused and frustrated. I have tried a lot of things that I found on the internet. I really do not understand why the download speed on my desktop is slower than my upload speed via my USB wifi dongle. I have tried 3 different dongles, each is some version of Realtek driver (RTL*).

Here is my speedtest output:

```
$ speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Ting Fiber (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by CCT (Wiggins, CO) [104.29 km]: 12.241 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 25.01 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 113.27 Mbit/s
```

Here is an attempt at me scp'ing a file from my laptop to the desktop and then back on the same wifi network (well, Google mesh network).

```
$ scp linux desktop.local:
linux                                                100%  134MB   3.3MB/s   00:41
$ scp desktop.local:linux .
linux                                                100%  134MB  15.2MB/s   00:08
```

As you can clearly see that the traffic to my desktop is about 5x slower than traffic from my desktop. And these `scp` commands are being executed on my laptop.

Turning off Wifi Powersave also did NOT help. However, I turned it back on.

Here is some helpful data:

```
$ lsmod | grep rtw
rtw88_8822bu           12288  0
rtw88_usb              24576  1 rtw88_8822bu
rtw88_8822b           229376  1 rtw88_8822bu
rtw88_core            356352  2 rtw88_usb,rtw88_8822b
mac80211             1724416  2 rtw88_core,rtw88_usb
cfg80211             1314816  2 rtw88_core,mac80211
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 10
       serial: bc:30:5b:9b:3a:f9
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=6.5.0-10-generic firmware=5761-v3.68 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:49 memory:f5de0000-f5deffff memory:f5df0000-f5dfffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: wlx90de80e6a2bf
       serial: 90:de:80:e6:a2:bf
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822bu driverversion=6.5.0-10-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.86.20 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

```
$ iwconfig
...
wlx90de80e6a2bf  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"HOMEWIFI"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: 24:05:88:36:76:99
          Bit Rate=390 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:32   Missed beacon:0
...
```

I am really hoping someone can help solve this problem. I am out of ideas and quite frustrated.

EDIT1:

```
$ speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Ting Fiber (0.0.0.0)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Highline (Denver, CO) [17.76 km]: 25.325 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 28.19 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 117.28 Mbit/s
$ ifconfig | grep mtu
br-ed9e125ad585: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
enp6s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
veth381ed2f: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
veth48a03b9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
vethe4c210c: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
vethe4d9061: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
wlx90de80e6a2bf: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your WiFi `MTU`, using

```
ip link
```

or

```
ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'
```

also notice your WiFi interface's name.

The `MTU` (Maximum Transmission Unit) is the size of the largest packet that can be sent in a single network transmission. If a packet exceeds the  `MTU` of a link, the data must be split into multiple packets (fragmented). These multiple packets must be sent over the link, received, acknowledged, and reassembled at the far end. If your link is misconfigured, and you have to fragment every packet you send, your actual data transfer rate drops.

Ethernet (wired)  networks use an `MTU` of 1500 bytes.

Due to additional per packet overhead for WiFi (8 bytes PPPoE header), WiFi uses an `MTU` of 1492.

Your `MTU` should be set by your DHCP server, check your router's config.

You can set your own `MTU` (setting does not persist over restarts) with

```
sudo ip link set dev name mtu 1492
```

where "name" is the interface name from above.

Here's an example:

```
walt@squid:~(0)$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp63s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:21:7f:e5:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxf46d04b1790f: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:6d:04:b1:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
walt@squid:~(0)$   sudo ip link set dev wlxf46d04b1790f mtu 1492
[sudo] password for walt: 
walt@squid:~(0)$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp63s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:21:7f:e5:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxf46d04b1790f: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:6d:04:b1:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

My WiFi "interface name" is "`wlxf46d04b1790f`".

Comment: `Due to additional per packet overhead for WiFi (8 bytes PPPoE header), WiFi uses an MTU of 1492.` What does WiFi have anything to do with PPPoE? It's a matter of your ISP. If it makes use of PPPoE, and say the overhead does requires the LAN hosts to adjust their MTU, it should be the same case to both the wired and wireless ones.

Comment: sorry it took me a while to try this suggestion. I had to replace the motherboard for an unrelated reason. As you can see from mu update above, I don't think it helped. It may have sped up both upload and download a little bit but downloads are still way slower.

Comment: I just noticed that your `ip link` output says `mtu 1492 qdisc mq state ...` whereas mine says: ```: wlx90de80e6a2bf: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:de:80:e6:a2:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: it has `noqueue` instead yours has `mq`. could that be the issue?